# Executing python script on Apache in MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, macos-sierra

I am trying to create a python script (widget.py) that will get a JSON feed from an arbitrary resource. I can't get the python script to execute on localhost. Here are the steps I have followed:

1. In `etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I enabled `LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so`
2. Restarted Apache `sudo apachectl restart`
3. Added a .htaccess file to my directory:

   `<Directory "widget.py">
     Options +ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .py
   </Directory>`

   NOTE: I will eventually need to deploy this on a server where I won't have access to the apache2 directory.
4. Navigated to `http://localhost/~walter/widget/widget.py`

I get a 500 server error. Log file contents:

`[Sat Jul 01 08:51:00.922413 2017] [core:info] [pid 75403] AH00096: removed PID file /private/var/run/httpd.pid (pid=75403)
[Sat Jul 01 08:51:00.922446 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 75403] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Sat Jul 01 08:51:01.449227 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 75688] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 01 08:51:01.449309 2017] [core:notice] [pid 75688] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'`

Do I need to enable cgi in `/etc/apache2/users/walter/http.conf`? Should I?

Answer (score 4):

Got it to work. Here are the steps that I followed:

1. In `etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I uncommented:

   `LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so`
2. Restarted Apache `sudo apachectl restart`
3. List itemAdded a .htaccess file to my directory with the following contents:

   `Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all`
4. Added `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of my python script
5. In terminal enabled execution of the python script using: `chmod +x widget.py`

Answer (score 1):

**Apache/WebSharing**

Their is no GUI to toggle Web Sharing on or off in OSX 10.10, which was previously a GUI option in System Preferences way back in 10.7, but fear not Apache is installed ready to be fired up.

This needs to be done in the Terminal which is found at **/Applications/Utilities/Terminal**

For those not familiar with the Terminal, it really isn’t as intimidating as you may think, once launched you are faced with a command prompt waiting for your commands – just type/paste in a command and hit enter, some commands give you no response – it just means the command is done, other commands give you feedback – lets get to it….

to start it

```
sudo apachectl start
```

to stop it

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

to restart it

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

To find the Apache version

```
httpd -v
```

The Apache version that comes in OSX Yosemite is Apache/2.4.10

After starting Apache – test to see if the webserver is working in the browser – http://localhost – you should see the “It Works!” text.

If you don’t get the localhost test, you can try troubleshooting Apache to see if there is anything wrong in its config file by running

`apachectl configtest` – Important to check configured properly or not

This will give you an indication of what might be wrong.

**Document Root**

Document root is the location where the files are shared from the file system and is similar to the traditional names of ‘**public_html**‘ and ‘**htdocs**‘, OSX has historically had 2 web roots one at a system level and one at a user level – you can set both up or just run with one, the user level one allows multiple accounts to have their own web root whilst the system one is global for all users. It seems there is less effort from Apple in continuing with the user level one but it still can be set up with a couple of extra tweaks in configuration files. It is easier to use the user level one as you don’t have to keep on authenticating as an admin user.
System Level Web Root
– the default system document root is still found at –
**http://localhost/**
The files are shared in the filing system at –

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/
```

**User Level Root**

The other web root directory which is missing by default is the ‘**~/Sites**’ folder in the User account. This takes a bit longer to set up but some users are very accustomed to using it.

You need to make a “**Sites**” folder at the root level of your account and then it will work. Once you make the Sites folder you will notice that it has a unique icon which is a throwback from a few versions older. Make that folder before you set up the user configuration file described next.

You have to make a few additional tweaks to get the **~/Sites** folder back up and running.

Create cgi-bin folder inside Sites folder and make permission cgi-bin as world-writable. If not a+rwx, then the folder is not writable

```
chmod a+rwx cgi-bin
```

Add  a “username.conf” filed under:

```
/etc/apache2/users/
```

If you don’t already have one (very likely), then create one named by the short username of the account with the suffix .**conf**, its location and permissions/ownership is best tackled by using the **Terminal**, the text editor ‘**nano**‘ would be the best tool to deal with this.

Launch **Terminal**, (Applications/Utilities), and follow the commands below, first one gets you to the right spot, 2nd one cracks open the text editor on the command line (swap ‘**username**‘ with your account’s shortname, if you don’t know your account shortname type ‘whoami‘ the Terminal prompt):

```
cd /etc/apache2/users
sudo nano accountname.conf
```

Then add the content below swapping in your ‘accountname’ in the code below:

```
<Directory "/Users/accountname/Sites/">
   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/accountname/Sites/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .tcl .py
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Uncomment server name and provide the domain name

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Permissions on the file should be:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  298 Jun 28 16:47 accountname.conf
```

If not you need to change…

```
sudo chmod 644 accountname.conf
```

Open the main httpd.conf and allow some modules:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And make sure these 4 modules are uncommented (the first 2 should be on a clean install):

```
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Search for  Update directory below permissions.

```
<Directory />
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Search for  and replace ScriptAliasMatch with ScriptAlias and replace with our custom Sites/cgi-bin folder path

```
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/Users/accountname/Sites/cgi-bin/"
```

Search for  and replace with our custom folder permission

```
<Directory "/Users/accountname/Sites/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</Directory>
```

Search for ‘**AddHandler**’ and add below handlers

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

If above line creates problem then commented it out
And also uncomment this configuration file also in **httpd.conf**

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

Then open another Apache config file and uncomment another file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

And uncomment:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

Restart Apache for the new file to be read:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Then this user level document root will be viewable at:

```
http://localhost/~accountname/
```

You should only see a directory tree like structure if the folder is empty.

**Override .htaccess and allow URL Rewrites**

If you are going to use the document root at /Library/WebServer/Documents it is a good idea to allow any .**htaccess** files used to override the default settings – this can be accomplished by editing the **httpd.conf** file at line 217 and setting the **AllowOverride** to **All** and then restart Apache. This is already taken care of at the Sites level webroot by following the previous step.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Also whilst here allow URL rewrites so your permalinks look clean not ugly.
Uncomment below line in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

**Python**

Once we create python file html code in provola.py, make it executable and place it inside ~/Sites/cgi-bin/ folder

```
sudo chmod +x provola.py
```

Restart the apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Ref link - http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Answer (score 0):

1, 2. Ok.

3. Are .htaccess files allowed in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf ?

`<Directory "widget.py">` — I think you want `<File "widget.py">`.

4. Look into error log — what is the error?

Comment: Changed to file and it didn't work. Log file doesn't show anything related. I added the logged errors above.

Comment: Also, yes .htaccess files are allowed. I set `AllowOverride All` in httpd.conf and restarted apache.

Comment: Actually, the problem seems to be the .htaccess file since navigating to the root of my directory the server returns a 500. If I remove the .htaccess no 500 is returned although my python script is not executed.

Comment: There have to be someting in the error log. Any chance you have different log files for different virtual servers?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If my .htaccess file contains only `AddHandler cgi-script .py` I can load the default page. But if I request `widget.py` it now says: `You don't have permission to access /~walter/widget/widget.py on this server.`

Comment: Apache 2.4+? You have to explicitly allow everything with directive `Require all granted`. In a <Directory>, I think. And of course Apache has to have access to /~walter/widget/widget.py and the file has to be executable.

Comment: Tried `Require all granted` and still not working. Do I have to wrap the contents in <Directory></Directory> tags? If I do that the server returns a 500 error. If I just have `AddHandler cgi-script .py
Require all granted` in my .htaccess

Comment: `<Directory></Directory>` required for /etc/apache2/httpd.conf but not fo .htaccess — the very place of .htaccess is the directory.